# Combining inheritance with the module pattern

Tags: javascript, inheritance, module, design-patterns

I like the module pattern that returns constructors as described in:
http://elegantcode.com/2011/02/15/basic-javascript-part-10-the-module-pattern/

However I am not sure how to inherit from an object that is implemented with this pattern. Suppose I have a parent object implemented thus...

```
namespace('MINE');  

MINE.parent = (function() { 
    // private funcs and vars here

    // Public API - constructor
    var Parent = function (coords) {
       // ...do constructor stuff here
    };

    // Public API - prototype
    Parent.prototype = {
       constructor: Parent,
       func1:  function ()    { ... },
       func2:  function ()    { ... }
    }

    return Parent;
 }());
```

How do I define a child object that also uses the module pattern that inherits from `parent` in such a way that I can selectively override, for example, `func2`?

Comment: Just a note, the code you've provided has a bug -- you're setting the constructor to `undefined`.  I've edited to fix it.

Comment: I just asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659326/simple-javascript-inheritance-using-extend-and-module-pattern - wondering what you think of it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
MINE.child = (function () {

  var Child = function (coords) {
    Parent.call(this, arguments);    
  }

  Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

  Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
  Child.prototype.func2 = function () { ... };

  return Child;

}());
```

Comment: Thank you. This was a very terse and clear answer and worked fine for me. I do like this pattern because it encompasses one-time initialization, encapsulation and with your code above, inheritance. Do you see any major pitfalls to the pattern?

Comment: @AndrewS. I personally hate namespaces. But that's a style preference. You can use module loaders instead.

Comment: This isn't working for me. If I were to instantiate a MINE.child, I can't access func1 (as defined in MINE.parent). Am I missing something?? And is the child's func2 supposed to replace the parent's func2?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you can have an equivalent of static variable, but not private variable. I'm still looking for a better way.

Comment: @juminoz the only non-horrendously-hacky way I know of doing private instance variables is to define them in the constructor and define all methods that rely on them in the constructor too, with this.method = .  Unfortunately I strongly dislike this way of doing things, as it creates a new function object for every instance rather than reusing the one on the prototype.  I tend to avoid using private instance variables for that reason.

Comment: private variables are easy. just use a weakmap keyed to `this`

Comment: @Raynos if you're writing es6 already then I envy you!  Having said that, if I were using es6, I'd probably use Symbols to do private variables.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution from this blog (http://metaduck.com/08-module-pattern-inheritance.html) cleaner. For example:

```
function Parent(name) {
    // Private variables here
    var myName;

    // Constructor
    myName = name;

    // Public interface
    return {
        func1: function () {alert("Parent func1. Name: " + myName); },
        func2: function () {alert("Parent func2. Name: " + myName); }
    }
}

function Child(name) {
    // Private variables here
    var myName,
        exportObj;

    // Constructor
    // Inherit
    exportObj = Parent(name + "'s father");

    // Override
    exportObj.func2 = function () {
        alert("Child func2. Name: " + name);
    }

    // Export public interface
    return exportObj;
}
```

An example can be run here: http://jsfiddle.net/wt4wcuLc/