# Inheritance: Constructor doesn't run "super"?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype, chaining

I've run into this behavior after using JS for a few months. I'm very puzzled because of my Java background: I create a class and make subclasses.
Call a subclass' constructor won't call the parent constructor. Ok, I read about this behavior, it seems normal, right?

See this jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2caTD/1/) to help me clarify.

So to have my subclass constructor run each of its parent constructor, I'm adding the following (see jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2caTD/3/)

Ok, seems to work better this way.
Now, I'm wondering about the following; Is there a way to specify wich is the superclass without trigger its constructor?
Like for instance the following runs the Node() method:

```
GameObject.prototype = new Node();
GameObject.prototype.constructor=GameObject;
```

(see updated jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2caTD/4/))

I can't help but feel I'm not doing it right. As my real model is layered across 7 subclasses, there's a total of 21 calls to my constructors (6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 21).

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you're doing it right. But your constructor function creates properties on its instances and those properties get assigned to the inheriting constructor's prototype.

`Subclass.prototype.animations`, for example are on the prototype, shared by all further instances of `Subclass`. From your code it seems like you intended these `animations` to be created anew for each instance.

How to resolve this problem? Don't use constructor functions at all. Use object literals and `Object.create`.

```
var Node = {
    init: function () { this.animations = []; },
    doSomething: function () { console.log(this.animations); }
};

var GameObject = Object.create(Node);
GameObject.doSomethingElse = function () { this.init(); this.doSomething(); }
```

Instantiate *the same way* you inherit:

```
var gameObj = Object.create(GameObject);
gameObj.doSomethingElse();
```

It shouldn't be more difficult than that.

See [Combining inheritance with the module pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683125/combining-inheritance-with-the-module-pattern).

Comment: Hey that sounds great, I like this idea of having a separate 'init' method. thanks!

Comment: So... Just don't use constructors? This is not a good way to fix the problem. The correct way is to use a different technique which doesn't involve calling the parent's constructor just to setup inheritance  http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

Comment: Also, `this.animations` is not set on the prototype, it's done on the object itself, writes are always on the object, never on the prototype (unless you do `Constructor.prototype.animations = []`), lastly, the suggestion to use `[]` is OK, but a better suggestion would have been to use `{}` since the OP is not using it as an array, but it's actually a map

Comment: @JuanMendes, `animations` becomes a property of the `Redhead` prototype, when he does `Redhead.prototype = new GameObject();`. I'll edit my answer to be express my take on (the absence of) constructors.

Comment: @Katspaugh I see, it's on the prototype because it's calling the constructor to setup inheritance and the instance of the parent is what gets attached to the prototype. Sorry, I should have realized that...

Comment: @JuanMendes, it's OK. I also see what you mean by the temporary constructor technique. May be useful!

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong, per-se.  This is the expected behavior given your code.  You can, however, use an approach similar to the one described in ["Simple JavaScript Inheritence" by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/).  Another discussion of a similar approach can be found [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598077/53162).

Comment: Calling the parent's constructor to setup inheritance **is** wrong

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that JavaScript doesn't naively implement classes the way traditional languages like C++, Java, and C# do. I think you can get the behaviour you want by using a JavaScript framework that imposes the behaviors you are used to in langauges like Java.

Moo Tools is one such framework: http://mootools.net

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call the parent's constructor just  to setup the inheritance chain. See http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

The following is bad, runs the parent's constructor just to setup the prototype chain

```
GameObject.prototype = new Node();
GameObject.prototype.constructor = GameObject;
```

The better way is to use a surrogate constructor that attaches the prototype without instantiating the "super class".

```
// Surrogate constructor
var TempCtor = function(){};
TempCtor.prototype = Node.prototype;
// Setup the prototype chain without side effects
GameObject.prototype = new tempCtor();
GameObject.prototype.constructor=GameObject;
```

And you need to make sure you call the parent constructor from the subclass

```
function GameObject() {
    // Call the parent's constructor
    Node.call(this);
}
```

I've updated your jsfiddle with an example that shows the correct way to setup inheritance http://jsfiddle.net/2caTD/5/