# Prototypal Inheritance in Module Pattern JavaScript - Base Class not inheriting anything from parent

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I just started to get into JS lately and I am using module pattern a lot and I really don't know if I am doing it right when it comes to doing inheritance from the module I wrote.

Here are the following .js files I am working on:

```
define(["src/Inhabitant"], function(Inhabitant)
{
  console.log("Coin.js loaded");

  return (function()
  {
    function Coin(stage , position)
    {
      Inhabitant.call(this, stage, position, "coinGold.png");
    }

    Coin.prototype = 
    {
        prototype   : Object.create(Inhabitant.prototype)
      , constructor : Coin
      , update      : update
    }

    function update(elapsed)
    {

    }

    return Coin;
  })();

});
```

I have a JS class named as `Coin` and its parent is `Inhabitant`:

```
define([], function()
{
  console.log("Inhabitant loaded.");

  return (function()
  {
    var mStage = null;
    var mSprite = null;
    var mID = -1;    

    function Inhabitant(stage, position , resource)
    {
      mStage = stage;
      mSprite = new PIXI.Sprite.fromFrame(resource);
      mSprite.position = position;
    }

    Inhabitant.prototype = 
    {
        constructor : Inhabitant

      , get position(){ return mSprite.position; } , set position(position){ mSprite.position = position; }
      , get x(){ return mSprite.x; } , set x(x){ mSprite.x = x; }
      , get y(){ return mSprite.y; } , set y(y){ mSprite.y = y; }

      , get id(){ return mID; } , set id(id){ return mID; }

      , get sprite(){ return mSprite; }

      , update : update
    }

    function update(elapsed)
    {
      console.log("Calling update from Inhabitant");
    }

    return Inhabitant;
  })();

});
```

I am stuck on this one because I can't even call the methods I am supposed to inherit. Even the update function isn't provided by the parent. If I remove the update from `Coin` it will not call the parent version (I don't know if I have the correct assumption on this one).

Also most of the time I write my classes this way

```
define([] , function()
{
    return function()
    {
        var o = {};

        return o
    }
});
```

This works most of the time since I am creating objects without the need of inheritance that much. But now I need to it in prototypal way so I can reduce code duplication.

What is the proper way of doing Module Pattern with prototypal inheritance given on what I currently have?

This have been asked many times via this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683125/combining-inheritance-with-the-module-pattern) and this [link](http://metaduck.com/08-module-pattern-inheritance.html) but its not helping my situation.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can return factory method (or fabric object), and not all modules code. It kills your performance. Factory method can look like `return { createCoin: function(params) { return new Coin(params) } }`. You can call it in another file, to get you Coin object `var coin = ModuleName.createCoin(params);` or for inheritance `function ChildObj(){}; ChildObj.prototype = new ModuleName.createCoin(params);` Read more about AMD here - http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html but note, that it's old things - http://benmccormick.org/2015/05/28/moving-past-requirejs/

Comment: So what I am encountering like some of the attributes are undefined is because of the limitation/my misuse of Module Pattern? Am I correct?